# Newbie to Rsync: From Windows to Linux

Tags: windows, linux, rsync

We are a small team and want to rsync our file changes to our test server which is linux.

I am trying to use cwRsync and here is what happens.

1. I downloaded and installed csRSync and create the key file
2. The linux server is our in-house test server and we use it with subdomains to upload our work.
3. How do I map the SSH key on my local machine with that linux machine? I can access it through putty with a local IP as well.

Answer (score 0):

Well first sync keys this can be done in putty enter

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa on local machine
```

then

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub | ssh user@hostname    ‘cat>>.ssh/authorized_keys’
```

or this can be done via winscp as your on a windows computer and copy it in to .ssh/authorized_keys’

The link below has more info on how to set it up

http://www.rsync.net/resources/howto/windows_rsync.html